# Android: change view visibility using ConstraintSet

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout, constraintset

I would like to change my view visibility using Contarint sets, I create two identical views but in second view I make my view visibility gone, actually when I run my activity it only shows the second XML where view visibility has already gone but no animation how its visibility has gone.

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/socialPart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/appName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/app_name_title"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_left" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/create_account"
                android:textColor="@color/title_color"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/facebook"
            style="@style/button_main"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/strock_rounded_button"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_facebook"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="0dp"
            android:text="@string/continue_facebook"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/google"
            style="@style/button_main"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/strock_rounded_button"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_google"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="0dp"
            android:text="@string/continue_google"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/useEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:background="#DADADA" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/use_register_email" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:background="#DADADA" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/main_button_size"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/strock_rounded_button"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_mail"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/hint_email"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/socialPart" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/main_button_size"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/strock_rounded_button"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_lock"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/hint_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/confirmPass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/main_button_size"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/strock_rounded_button"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_lock"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/hint_confirm_pass"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/termAndServices"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
        android:text="@string/term_and_condition"
        android:textColor="#4D4D4D"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/confirmPass" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        style="@style/button_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/gray"
        android:text="@string/get_started"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

my main layout where socialPart is Visible

```
androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/socialPart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/app_name_title"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_left" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/create_account"
            android:textColor="@color/title_color"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/facebook"
        style="@style/button_main"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/strock_rounded_button"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_facebook"
        android:drawablePadding="20dp"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:text="@string/continue_facebook"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/google"
        style="@style/button_main"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/strock_rounded_button"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_google"
        android:drawablePadding="20dp"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:text="@string/continue_google"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/useEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:background="#DADADA" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/use_register_email" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:background="#DADADA" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/main_button_size"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/strock_rounded_button"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_mail"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:hint="@string/hint_email"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/socialPart" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/main_button_size"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/strock_rounded_button"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_lock"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:hint="@string/hint_password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/confirmPass"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/main_button_size"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/strock_rounded_button"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_lock"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:hint="@string/hint_confirm_pass"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/termAndServices"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
    android:text="@string/term_and_condition"
    android:textColor="#4D4D4D"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/confirmPass" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login"
    style="@style/button_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/gray"
    android:text="@string/get_started"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

what I want to have in the end, but when I run my application it shows the second view where visibility is already gone and there is no any animation

Comment: Can you post some code example of what you've done ? Maybe even show us some screenshots of whats happening and what you would like it to do ? Thanks

Comment: you can check now

Comment: Still need to see the code where you transition between the layouts.